# Como almaceno una imagen en SQLite y luego mostrarla en una ImageView en Android Estudio

Tags: imagen

Estoy realizando una aplicación para almacenar una imagen en SqLite y luego mostrarla en un ImageView.
Yo he logrado seleccionar seleccionar una imagen de mi galeria de fotos y mostrarla en un ImageVIew; pero no he conseguido almacenarla en mi base de Datos Sqlite y luego mostrarla en un ImageView.

Alguna sugerencia??

Comment: La primera sugerencia es que coloques tu codigo, la segunda es que guardes la imagen en el telefono y la direccion y nombre de la imagen en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo una sugerencia que podrías incorporar con Bitmap.

El procedimiento para guardar los imágenes desde un Bitmap seria:

- comprimir el bitmap en un ByteArrayOutputStream
- escribir el byte[] del stream como blob en tu tabla
- se asume una tabla CREATE TABLE imagenes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, img BLOB); con un SQLiteOpenHelper helper

public void guardarImagen(long id, Bitmap bitmap){

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(20480);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0 , baos);
        byte[] blob = baos.toByteArray();

        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    
        String sql = "INSERT INTO imagenes (id, img) VALUES(?,?)";
        SQLiteStatement insert = db.compileStatement(sql);
        insert.clearBindings();
        insert.bindLong(1, id));
        insert.bindBlob(2, blob);
        insert.executeInsert();
        db.close();
    }
```